# Abstract class usage

Tags: java

When using abstract classes in an application, I came across two possible ways to access data in abstract classes. Would one be preferred over the other because of its context of being an within an abstract class?

```
public abstract class Example {

       private String name;

       public Example(String name) {
            this.name = name;
       }

       //other methods that can be overridden in child classes
}

public class ExampleTwo extends Example {

       public ExampleTwo() {
            super("ExampleTwo");
       }
}
```

---

or would it be better to simply override a returning method with a value, given the same output. For example:

```
public abstract class Example {

       public abstract String getName();

       //other methods that can be overridden in child classes
}

public class ExampleTwo extends Example {

       @Override
       public String getName() {
             return "ExampleTwo";
       }

}
```

Comment: Eh.  Whichever you want.

Comment: What are the 2 ways? And what is the question?

Comment: I'm assuming in cases like these, design does not matter in the end, since they will both be producing the same end result?

Comment: @ACV In my first example, I simply provide the input via a constructor and have the parent class hold the String variable. In the second, I simply override a parent method to return a value.

Comment: A difference would be if you actually need it to be a function, i.e. if the string in this case varies from one call to another. In general though, it's just whichever you prefer.

Comment: If you need the name in the constructor, use the first way. You shouldn't call overridable methods in the constructor.

Comment: @slees2043 what is your use case? Depends on what you need.

Comment: @ACV As said on one of the answers, I'm simply providing the parent class with some metadata given from the child class in the constructor, and having some other override-able methods. I was unsure if I should continue with this current design or simply have override-able methods in the child classes to provide their own meta data.

Comment: You can use both - use constructor and methods for sending the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for a start, these two approaches are completely different from one another.  Your first example will never expose your `name` variable to its children since it's `private`.  Your second example mandates that every child implements `getName` as part of its API.

Ultimately it depends on what you want to accomplish.

In the first case I would presume that you're establishing some kind of conventional state for your classes, and your children needed to supply the parent with a bit of metadata so that the parent's methods could respond correctly.  Think of an Animal hierarchy; you'd define `makeSound` in the parent, but each child would tell it how to speak.

In the second case I'd favor an interface over abstract classes, as you're not getting any wins from inheritance in that approach.

Comment: Yup, as said I'm provided a bit of metadata to the parent from the child to help identify it, and currently using the first example mentioned in my projects layout.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing two different scenarios. In the first `name` is a variable which is set in the constructor and read with its getter. The second defines a `getName` method which can return anything, e.g. a random string.